# Default values to reference, c++

Tags: c++, reference, return, default

So I've made a linked list which holds REFERENCES for class objects I created.

I want to do a method which searches in the linked list and returning a const reference to the object if it exists, or else, if object doesn't exist, returns SOME VALUE.

which value should it be? if it was int, I'd return 0, if it was pointer, I'd return NULL....

```
const Node& NodeList::NodeNumSearch(int num) const
{
    Member *TempHead=MemberHead;
    while(TempHead!=NULL)
    {
        if(TempHead->GetNode().getNum() == num)
            return TempHead->GetNode();
        TempHead=TempHead->GetNext();
    }

    return ???;
}
```

P.S. a Member object is a member of the linked list. and a Node object is the value in the Member objects of the linked list.

Comment: You could `throw` an exception. You could return a reference to a static, semantically null `Node`. You could use Boost.Optional. What you must never, ever do is `return *(Node*)0`.

Comment: Or return a pointer instead and use nullptr, or return an iterator and use the one-past-the-end to signal "not found."

Comment: References are simply not well suited for this.

Comment: Yes, a pointer makes more sense in this case.

Comment: In C++; having a reference implies having an object. If a function returns a reference, it is *guaranteeing* that that reference will refer to a valid object. If you want the possibility of returning `NULL`, you return a pointer (or an iterator, as others have pointed out, but then again a pointer is like an iterator).

Comment: Change your interface. You could have a proxy class, perhaps called `ambulator`, that represents an abstract cursor walking over the list elements, and as long as it doesn't have some special value, like `finish()`, it would be possible to call a special member function on it that returns the reference to the original list element which to which it corresponds. But perhaps that's a crazy idea.

Answer (score 4):

Either `throw` an exception in this case, or change your function to return by pointer instead. There just isn't a sane way to return an "empty" reference here.

Alternately take the standard library approach and return an interator-like proxy by value, and you can then check it for `end`ness.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your own NullNode as a static member var and return it.

```
// header
class NodeList
{
    .....

    static Node k_NullNode;
};


// cpp
/* static */ Node NodeList::k_NullNode; // you might need to pass a special argument to make it different from normal nodes.

const Node& NodeList::NodeNumSearch(int num) const
{
    ....

    return k_NullNode;
}

// test
void test()
{
    const Node& ret = NodeNumSearch(0);
    if( ret == NodeList::k_NullNode ) // you might need to override == operator.
    {
        // failed to search..
    }
    else
    {
        // succeeded..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in C/C++, typically you pass a pointer to hold the result, and actually return a value based on whether or not the function worked. Alternatively, you should throw an exception if it doesn't work rather than pass back a default object. Only pass defaults back if you expect you want that default to be used by other code - for a search that seems unlikely.

```
// Inject Node pointer to hold the reference
// Returns 1 if it worked, 0 otherwise
const int NodeList::NodeNumSearch(int num, Node* node) const
{
  //your code here
}
```

Comment: This would be the C way of doing it but isn't normally used in C++ where other methods like exceptions exist.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm a fan of exceptions, but have mostly used them in Java.